# Third div doesn't fill the space below the first one

Tags: html, css

I have three divs with some content. On a wide screen they are all in one row. When I resize the screen, the following happens:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiFXY.png)

I want the bottom div to fill the space below the top one, like this [Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUZ8x.jpg). Also on small screen all three divs should stack up in one column, so adding float:right to right div doesn't work. I'm doing it for email in web Outlook, so can't use media queries.

Here's the code

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

div {
  background: red;
  margin: 10px;
}

#top {
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#bottom {
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#right {
  width: auto;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div id="top">111111111111111111</div>
<div id="right">2222</div>
<div id="bottom">333333333333333</div>
```

Will be thankful for some advice on this situation.

Comment: with outlook your best approach would be using a table, or an image...

Answer (score 1):

**Method1)** use of `%` :

1) you must use of `%` instead of `px` for `width` and `margin`, for example:

```
div {
    width: 30%;
    //Other css...
}
```

2) use of `word-break: break-all;`

3) I remove `width` of `id`s and `margin:10px`(you can use of `%` for margin,i remove it because `display:inline-block` insert a margin automatically)

```css
div {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 50px; 
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    border: 2px solid black;
    background: red;
    width: 30%;
    word-break: break-all;
}

#top {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

#bottom {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

#right {
    height: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div id="top">111111111111111111</div>
<div id="right">2222</div>
<div id="bottom">333333333333333</div>
```

**Method2)** use of `flex` :

```css
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
div:not(.wrapper) {
    font-size: 50px; 
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    border: 2px solid black;
    background: red;
    word-break: break-all;
    flex-grow: 1;

}

#top {
    vertical-align: top;
    
}

#bottom {
    vertical-align: top;
}

#right {
    height: 200px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="top">111111111111111111</div>
    <div id="right">2222</div>
    <div id="bottom">333333333333333</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Now divs are always in one row. But I want the bottom div to fill the space below the top one when resizing the screen, like this:[link](https://imgur.com/DSqE7Qe)

Comment: @M0_salah , you must use of Media queries.

Comment: Ehsan, Outlook doesn't support them